# Why do I sometimes get a stack trace when hiding a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment that has inner fragments.

```
public void hideInnerFragment(String fr_tag) {  
  FragmentTransaction childTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
  MyInnerFragment inner = (MyInnerFragment)   getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fr_tag);  
  if(inner != null) {  
      childTransaction.hide(inner);  
      childTransaction.commit();  
    }  
}
```

Works fine. 
But I have seen some times in the logs a stacktrace like the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1377)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1395)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:637)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:616)
at com.test.MyParentFragment.hideInnerFragment
```

Why do I get this one? I haven't figured out when this happens.

**Update:**
Just in case it helps/matters:
When the fragment is created I start an async task to do a long running operation and depending upon the result I call the hide of the inner fragment.

Comment: What do you do with `childTransaction` in case `inner` is `null`? Seems it stays open.

Comment: I get this issue too sometimes

Comment: @Sva.Mu: If `null` I don't do anything. What should I be doing?

Comment: It seems you sometimes begin a transaction, but not always close it (commit/rollback). This is very likely unrelated to your issue, but still - you should only open transaction in case you _know_ you will need it (i.e. when `inner != null`).

Comment: @Sva.Mu: So the first 2 lines should be reversed and the second line inside the if condition?

Comment: Yes, you should begin transaction inside of the `if` block.

Comment: @Sva.Mu:I added an update in the OP

Comment: Hey Jim, I guess I got it ! you are playing with fragments after onSaveInstance( ), since you are using child fragment means you are using support fragment and Google had bug in support fragment  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23761. Fix : commit the transaction will loss i,e childTransaction.AllowingStateLossCommit()

Comment: @dex:So the only change I need to do is replace `childTransaction.commit();` with `childTransaction.AllowingStateLossCommit();`  to fix this?

Comment: @Jim, I guess it will work, I have posted some more alternatives ways to it !   hope fully it will provide some help.

Comment: @Jim has this work for you ?

Comment: @dex:I don't know how to verify this. I don't know which steps do this. I have seen this exception in the logs. Do you have an idea of what steps I can do to actually see this happening?

Comment: Do these operation in onActivityResults method, if using android M do these operations in onRequestPermissionResult , definitely you will see a crash with same logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91027/discussion-between-dex-and-jim).

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you calling the method "hideInnerFragment" from an async task or something that is called after onPause() has been called.

I had a similar problem in my last app and I solved this by having a public static boolean in the hostactivity.

```
public HostActivity extends Activity(){
     public static boolean visible = false; // set it to false; 

 public void onResume(){
     visible = true;
 }

 public void onPause(){
     visible = false;
 }

}
```

then in your fragment

```
public void hideInnerFragment(String fr_tag) 
{ 
  if(HostActivity.visible)
  { 
      FragmentTransaction childTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
      MyInnerFragment inner = (MyInnerFragment)   getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fr_tag);  
      if(inner != null) {  
       childTransaction.hide(inner);  
       childTransaction.commit();  
     }  
}
```

Comment: Mark,  if activity extends from FragmentActivity then we can do all our fragment related operation safely in onFragmentResume() method . Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I wasn't using FragmentActivity  in my project but I think that you are right and it would work, but I have never done it

Comment: @dex:Yes in my case I extend `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending from FragmentActivity, then do all your operation related to fragment transaction inside onResumeFragments() method.

Alternatively You replace childTransaction.commit();  with childTransaction. commitAllowingStateLoss().

Alternatively you can override your onSaveInstance method and don't call super of it.

All this is happening because support fragment had a bug which is already reported to Google code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23761